# Firefox Extension trouble using port.emit and port.on

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I can't seem to get port.emit working correctly with my Firefox extension. From the init() function in popup.js the messages are correctly sent to main.js using addon.port.emit. Once they've been sent, the giveStorage message is correctly received in popup.js. However, this only works correctly when the original message is sent in the init function.

When I try sending the messages using using the jQuery change listener, the logs "Storage has been set." and "Sending storage to popup.js" come through, so popup.js is just not receiving it, but I have no idea why not. Only messages are logged correctly when ran from the init function.

If anyone has any ideas, or if you need any more information, please let me know and I'll see what I can do. Any help is greatly appreciated!

main.js

```
panel.port.on("setStorage", function (text) {
  console.log("Storage has been set.");
  ss.storage[text[0]] = text[1];
})

panel.port.on("getStorage", function (text) {
  console.log("Sending storage to popup.js");
  panel.port.emit("giveStorage", [text, ss.storage[text]])
})
```

popup.js

```
function init(){
    $(".panel").hide();
    addon.port.emit("getStorage", "username");
    addon.port.emit("getStorage", "volume");
    setInterval(function(){following();}, 60000);
}

addon.port.on("giveStorage", function (text) {
    console.log("Message received from main.js");
    if (text[1] !== null) {
        if (text[0] === "username") {
            username = text[1];
            $('#menuFollowing').click();
        }
        else if (text[0] === "volume"){
            volume = text[1];
            $("#volume").val(volume);
            $('#volumeValue').empty();
            $('#volumeValue').append('Volume: ' + volume);
        }
    }
})

$('#volume').change(function(){
    volume = $('#volume').val();
    addon.port.emit("setStorage", ["volume", volume]);
    addon.port.emit("getStorage", "volume");
});
```

Complete main.js

```
var { ToggleButton } = require('sdk/ui/button/toggle');
var panels = require("sdk/panel");
var self = require("sdk/self");
var ss = require("sdk/simple-storage");
var notifications = require("sdk/notifications");

var panel = panels.Panel({
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    contentURL: self.data.url("popup.html"),
    onHide: handleHide,
  });

var button = ToggleButton({
  id: "hitbox-plus",
  label: "hitbox Plus",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon16.png",
    "48": "./icon48.png",
  },
  onChange: handleChange,
});

function handleChange(state) {
  panel.contentURL = self.data.url("popup.html");
  if (state.checked) {
    panel.show({
      position: button
    });
  }
}

function handleHide() {
  button.state('window', {checked: false});
}

panel.port.on("getStorage", function (text) {
  console.log("Sending storage to popup.js");
  panel.port.emit("giveStorage", [text, ss.storage[text]])
})

panel.port.on("setStorage", function (text) {
  console.log("Storage has been set.");
  ss.storage[text[0]] = text[1];
})
```

Comment: Can you add enough of the code from main.js that people could copy it and run the code? Help us help you, basically.

Comment: @canuckistani My complete main.js has been added. #volume is a html range, if that helps at all.